# Doctrine: Switch database first approach to code first approach

Tags: doctrine-orm

In the past, at our project it was decided to use Doctrine with "database first" approach and about 30 tables have already been processed.

We would like switch to the "code first" approach.

Is it possible to somehow build on already finished things or does the whole work have to start from scratch? How to proceed?

Thanks for the advice.

Comment: It's unclear what kind of assistance is desired. If you have a DB model why can't you write code that uses it?

Comment: What do you mean by "processed"? How do these approaches differ?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to generate Doctrine entities based on an existing database schema.
There is some support by Doctrine to do this which cannot handle every case but should get you started.

```
php doctrine orm:convert-mapping --from-database yml /path/to/mapping-path-converted-to-yml
```

For more information see e.g. documentation [here](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/current/reference/tools.html#reverse-engineering)